# Iterating files while in write mode

Tags: python

```
FOLDER1
  FOLDER2
     FOLDER3
     $$FOLDER4
```

I need just `FOLDER3` as my output printed as `FOLDER3.txt`. Here goes my code, i want to iterate Folder while in write mode.

```
import os,sys
path="O:\\103"
dir=os.listdir(path)
for file in dir:
dir=os.path.join(path,file)
print dir
os.system("dir /b "+dir+" > "+file+".txt")
with open('file','r') as f:
#f.readline()
   text=f.read()
   print text
   f.close()
   with open('f','w') as yyy:
   for xxx in yyy:
   if all(not xxx.startswith(x) for x in ('$')):
    p=xxx.split("_")[0]
    print p
    f.writelines(str(p)+"\n")
yyy.close()
```

Comment: @VaughnCato and indentation. Pretty sure some is missing.

Comment: @jozzas a lot is missing - and `with open('file','r') as f` should really be `with open(file,'r') as f`, although one should not use `file` as a variable name since its a [built-in](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects).

Comment: while reading and writing the contents of FOLDER1 i.e FOLDER2 i want to read and write the contents of FOLDER2 i.e FOLDER3

Answer (score 1):

I will highlight problems in  your code; which should help you along. It is not clear what you really want to do.

```
import os,sys

path="O:\\103" # this should be r'O:\103'
dir=os.listdir(path)
for file in dir: # do not use file as a variable name as its a built-in
    dir=os.path.join(path,file) # here you are overwriting the `dir` variable
    print dir
    os.system("dir /b "+dir+" > "+file+".txt")
    with open('file','r') as f: # 'file' is a string, file is a variable
        #f.readline()
        text=f.read()
        print text
    f.close() # you don't need to close the file if you use a with statement.
    with open('f','w') as yyy: # here you are trying to open the string 'f'
       for xxx in yyy:
           # this should be if not xxx.startswith('$'):
           if all(not xxx.startswith(x) for x in ('$')):
               p=xxx.split("_")[0]
               print p
               f.writelines(str(p)+"\n") # what is f here? This should be
                                         # .write()
                                         # writelines() takes a sequence
        yyy.close() # again, no need to close
```

---

If you have a directory `/home/vivek/test` and inside it you have this:

```
.
└── vivek
    ├── v1
    │   ├── A.txt
    │   ├── B.txt
    │   └── C.txt
    └── v2
        ├── D.txt
        ├── E.txt
        └── F.txt
```

Your goal is to print the file names (or open the file names and print their contents):

```
import os

root_path = '/home/vivek/test'
files = []
for parent,directory,file_list in os.walk(root_path):
   if file_list:
      for filename in file_list:
          files.append(os.path.join(parent,filename))
```

This will give you a list of the full path to the files, like this:

```
['/home/vivek/test/vivek/v2/E.txt',
 '/home/vivek/test/vivek/v2/D.txt',
 '/home/vivek/test/vivek/v2/F.txt',
 '/home/vivek/test/vivek/v1/C.txt',
 '/home/vivek/test/vivek/v1/B.txt',
 '/home/vivek/test/vivek/v1/A.txt']
```

Now, you can do whatever you like:

```
for filename in files:
   with open(filename) as f:
       print f.readlines()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot burhan as i am new to python i need this kind instructions.
I just want to know 
   os.system("dir /b "+dir+" > "+file+".txt")
   with open('file','r') as f:
when i am writing the +file+.txt file what should i use in with open () to read that file again ???

Comment: VIVEK(A folder)
----------------------------------------------------------------
V1(A folder)
[inside V1]
 
A B C D(4 files)
---------------------------------------------------------------
V2
[inside V2]
 
E F G H
--------------------------------------------------------------
 
I need to iterate through VIVEK
Thn READ V1 V2 
and finally iterate through V1 V2 
 
 
and print A B C D E F G H